# Auth.NET API Refund more than 180 days

Tags: authorize.net, credit-card, credits

I have a customer who wants us to roll back all monthly charges for the last 18 months, and redo them on a different card (long story, they feel they have a legitimate ask)

I see in the documentation, it says the 'default' is that I can refund up to 180 days.

Is there any way to go beyond 180 days on refunds if 180 is the default?  Is there a way to change that 180 day limit to 18 months, at least, for a short time?

I have no problem doing credits, and reauthing on a different card.
I just need to know how to get past the 180 days, if that's even possible.
I do have all auth codes and transaction ids that I need to go back 18 months.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net calls this [Expanded Credit Capabilities](https://account.authorize.net/help/Miscellaneous/Pop-up_Terms/Expanded_Credit_Capabilities.htm). The client would need to complete the form provided in the link.